# How to connect to MongoDB in Windows?

Tags: windows, mongodb

I'm trying to run Mongo from the Command-Line: 
What's wrong? (I've IIS on localhost:80). And Apache on port 8080. Are there any issues 
with this?

```
C:\MONGO\Project1\mongo\bin>mongo --port 27017
MongoDB shell version: 2.0.3
connecting to: 127.0.0.1:27017/test
Sat Mar 10 16:16:45 Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017 shell/mong
o.js:86
exception: connect failed
```

Comment: Check if there is something using that port. in cmd: netstat -ano | findstr 27017

Comment: Hey I came across the same problem and solved it by removing .lock file from \data\db folder and everything worked fine from there ! :)

Comment: @Muhammad Riyaz how did you remove the lock file on windows 8 im trying \data\db\mongod.lock and it's just asking how i want to open the file.

Comment: @phil i just deleted the .lock file :) to be safe just cut and paste this file somewhere else and check if mongodb works. If it does (i m sure it will) you can dekete this .lock file

Comment: A lot of the answers are plain confusing or obsolete. Go to the MSDN article - https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Mongo-Database-setup-on-6963f46f

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Did you create the default db path?
It defaults to "`/data/db` directory (or `c:\data\db` on Windows)"
Source: http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Starting+and+Stopping+Mongo

Comment: C:\data\db - there is the path.. I thought it would create a path in the subfolder of the project, actually that I find a much nicer solution.

Comment: You can use a custom path, here's mine : mongod --dbpath /Mongo/db.
This starts mongo in c:\mongo and the db is in c:\mongo\db

Comment: What about when creating a web application. What about security and paths?

Comment: I installed mongo in e: so I needed to create e:/data/db

Answer (score 56):

I found that when I got this error it wasn't because I didn't have my default db path set up. It was because I was trying to run mongo.exe **before** running mongod.exe.

Comment: this is indeed great advice.

Comment: This should be the actual answer! That change in one letter is all that is needed. When searching for the exe, cmd auto completes to mongo.exe when tab is pressed. :D

Comment: Fixed either - why official docs not telling about this with bold text =)

Answer (score 26):

1. As Admin, create directory:

   ```
   mkdir c:\mongo\data\db
   ```
2. As Admin, install service:

   ```
   .\mongod.exe --install --logpath c:\mongo\logs --logappend --bind_ip 127.0.0.1 --dbpath c:\mongo\data\db --directoryperdb
   ```
3. Start MongoDB:

   ```
   net start MongoDB
   ```
4. Start Mongo Shell:

   ```
   c:\mongo\bin\mongo.exe
   ```

Comment: Very useful. Thanks.For the people trying this solution, notice that the "As Admin" is very important ;)

Answer (score 9):

Follow

1. Create default db folder.

   **c:\data\db**

   and also log folder

   **c:\data\log\mongo.log**

   or use following commands in command-prompt

   ```
   mkdir c:\data\log    
   mkdir c:\data\db
   ```
2. Create config file in bin folder of mongo (or you may in save your desired destination).

   Add following in text file named "mongod" and save it as
   **mongod.cfg**
   **dbpath=c:\data\db**
   **logpath=c:\data\log\mongo.log**

   or use following commands in command-prompt

   ```
   echo dbpath=c:\data\db>> "mongod.cfg"
   echo logpath=c:\data\log\mongo.log>> "mongod.cfg"
   ```
3. Now open command-prompt (administrator) and run the following command to start mongo server

   ```
   mongod
   ```
4. Open another command-prompt (don't close 1st prompt) and run client command:

   ```
   mongo
   ```

Hope this will help or you have done this already.

Comment: +1 For point 4. that allows you to monitor what is actually happening if you complete 1., 2. and 3, with mongo as a service

Comment: Should we type mongod in command prompt every time we want to start mongo server?

Answer (score 5):

The error occurs when trying to run mongo.exe WITHOUT having executed mongod.exe.
The following batch script solved the problem:

```
@echo off
cd C:\mongodb\bin\
start mongod.exe
start mongo.exe
exit
```

Answer (score 4):

If you are getting these type of errors when running **mongod** from command line or running mongodb server, 
[image]

 then follow these steps,

1. Create **db** and **log** directories in C: drive 
   C:/data/db and C:data/log
2. Create an empty log file in **log** dir named **mongo.log**
3. Run **mongod** from command line to run the mongodb server or create a batch file on desktop which can run the mongod.exe file from your mongodb installation direction. That way you just have to click the batch file from your desktop and mongodb will start.
4. If you have 32-bit system, try using **--journal** with **mongod** command.

Comment: This answer helped for me quick. "try using --journal with mongod command."

Comment: I had previous version of mongodb 3.0 and after installation version 3.6 I had the same problem. Resolved by removing everything inside c:/data/log and run mongod

Answer (score 2):

Create default db folder.

```
c:\data\db
```

and also log folder

```
c:\data\log\mongo.log
```

or use `following` commands in command-prompt

```
mkdir c:\data\log    
mkdir c:\data\db
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use below command,

```
mongod --dbpath=D:\home\mongodata
```

where **D:\home\mongodata** is the **data storage path**

Answer (score 1):

1. Go to **C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.4\bin** using cmd and
   write mongod.
2. Open another cmd by right click and **run as admin** point to your
   monogodb installed directory as mentioned above and then just like
   write this `mongo.exe`
3. After that, write `db.test.save({Field:'Hello mongodb'})` this command
   will insert a field having name Field and value is **Hello
   mongodb**.
4. After, check the record `db.test.find()` and press enter you will find
   the record that you have recently entered.

Comment: I.e. you have to run `mongod` to start server and `mongo` to run client that will use a server.

Answer (score 1):

Steps to start a certain local MongoDB instance and to connect to in from NodeJS app:

1. Create `mongod.cfg` for a new database using the path `C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\4.0\mongod.cfg` with the content

   ```
   systemLog:
     destination: file
     path: C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\4.0\log\mongod.log
   storage:
     dbPath: C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\4.0\data\db
   ```
2. Install mongoDB database by running

   `mongod.exe --config "C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\4.0\mongod.cfg" --install`
3. Run a particular mongoDB database

   `mongod.exe --config "C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\4.0\mongod.cfg"`
4. Run mongoDB service

   ```
   mongo 127.0.0.1:27017/db
   ```

   and !see mongoDB actual connection string to coonect to the service from NodeJS app

   ```
   MongoDB shell version v4.0.9
   connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/db?gssapiServiceName=mongodb
   Implicit session: session { "id" : UUID("c7ed5ab4-c64e-4bb8-aad0-ab4736406c03") }
   MongoDB server version: 4.0.9
   Server has startup warnings:
   ...
   ```

Answer (score 0):

For this error, if you are using windows 7 or windows server 2008 R2, the problem could be that you have to install a microsoft hotfix.

Refer to this link: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2731284