# Couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017 on Windows 7

Tags: windows, mongodb

I have problem with connecting to the server on mongodb:

```
mongo
MongoDB shell version: 3.0.1
connecting to: test
Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017 src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:179
exception: connect failed
```

Comment: sorry but answers in this link for Linux, I`m using MongoDB on WINDOWS

Comment: Sorry, you are right, comment deleted.

Comment: Ok, what about this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9647561/how-to-connect-to-mongodb-in-windows

Comment: Probably means the server isn't running, or perhaps is running but for some reason is not using the expected port number.  You can use `netstat -a -n` to look to see whether anything is listening on 27017 or not.

Answer (score 1):

- Set up the MongoDB environment (MongoDB’s default data directory path is \data\db):

  ```
  md \data\db
  ```
- Start MongoDB (Assuming MongoDB is at "C:\mongodb")

  ```
  C:\mongodb\bin\mongod.exe
  ```
- Connect to MongoDB

  ```
  C:\mongodb\bin\mongo.exe
  ```

More Details [here](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-windows/).

Answer (score 0):

Run the mongod server:
mongod --dbpath /root/hemant/mongodb_data/data/db

Once the server started listening to the port 27017.
Run the mongo.exe

You might get an error like below:
Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017 src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:179
exception: connect failed

Restart the machine, this works in my case.